# while loop not giving correct results

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to JS.
Now i am trying to code a script where when i buy a mobile the price get deducted from my credit card price.
here is the code

```
    // Total Money in my Credit Card
var totalMoneyForCredit=150;

// Your Current Billing from Shop
var moneySpent=0;

// Prices of Phones
var samsungPrice=33;
var sonyPrice=22;
var nokiaPrice=22;

// Asseorices for mobile

var charger=5;
var headset=10;


// Ask user for Purchasing Which mobies


while(totalMoneyForCredit>0){
    var order=prompt("Please enter the mobile you want to Purchase");
    if (order==='sam') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+samsungPrice;

        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-moneySpent;

    }
    else if (order==='nokia') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+nokiaPrice;
        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-moneySpent;


    }

    else if (order==='sony') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+sonyPrice;

        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-moneySpent;

    }
    document.write(  '<b>' +  ' You spent ' + moneySpent  + " and the money left in your credit is " + totalMoneyForCredit + '</br>');

}
```

**It's working fine but when i shop for nokia or any phone for the 4th time the prices are displayed incorrectly.**

[image: Snapshot]

**How come i spent 88 out of 150 and still money left is -70.**
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Your incrementing `moneySpent` and then subtracting that amount from what you had, I would suggest subtracting the phone price instead

Comment: I'm amazed you think the first 3 are correct and only the fourth is wrong

Comment: oh sorry!! I didnt see that.

Comment: ok got it. Thanks. But how do i send a message when money is in - rather than showing result.. eg. you have run out of cash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, subtracting the phone price from total money instead of total money from remaining amount.

```js
    // Total Money in my Credit Card
var totalMoneyForCredit=150;

// Your Current Billing from Shop
var moneySpent=0;

// Prices of Phones
var samsungPrice=33;
var sonyPrice=22;
var nokiaPrice=22;

// Asseorices for mobile

var charger=5;
var headset=10;


// Ask user for Purchasing Which mobies


while(totalMoneyForCredit>0){
    var order=prompt("Please enter the mobile you want to Purchase");
    if (order==='sam') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+samsungPrice;

        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-samsungPrice;

    }
    else if (order==='nokia') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+nokiaPrice;
        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-nokiaPrice;


    }

    else if (order==='sony') {
        moneySpent=moneySpent+sonyPrice;

        totalMoneyForCredit=totalMoneyForCredit-sonyPrice;

    }
    console.log(' You spent ' + moneySpent  + " and the money left in your credit is " + totalMoneyForCredit);

}
alert('You ran out of money!');
```

Comment: thanks depperm and what if i display a message so that i cannot see the - money. i mean simply display a message saying you ran out of cash.Thaks.

Comment: added an alert for when you run out of money

Answer (score 0):

You spent 88 out of 18 remaining from previous transactions. So you have 18-88=-70 remaining.